# If I pass WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE to RegisterWaitForSingleObject, do I need to later call UnregisterWait?

Tags: winapi

I am using [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to watch a directory for changes. I only need to be notified of the first change so I am passing `WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE`. Everything is fine so far.

My question is: do I still need to cancel the wait operation in this case with either `UnRegisterWait` or `UnRegisterWaitEx` or is that done automatically once the operation signals or times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to dispose of the handle;

> When the wait is completed, you must call the UnregisterWait or
>   UnregisterWaitEx function to cancel the wait operation. **(Even wait
>   operations that use WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE must be canceled.)** Do not make
>   a blocking call to either of these functions from within the callback
>   function.

Comment: D'oh! I guess I should read the Remarks more carefully. "RTFM" would also have been an appropriate answer ;p Thanks.